# The given two spaces are homotopic.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $$X=S^1\cup \{0\}\times [-1,1]\ \text{and } Y=\{S^1+(1,0)\}\cup \{S^1+(-1,0)\}.$$ Are these two spaces homotopic?

I can see it in the picture that they are homotopic. As in the line if we identify $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$ then we will get figure 8 which is homotopic to $Y$. But how do I show it mathematically?

[image: space X and Y]

Comment: Hint: Show that both $X$ and $Y$ are deformation retracts of $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{\pm1/2\}$ by using straight line homotopies.

Comment: Could you please tell how $ \mathbb{C}$ is coming to the picture?

Comment: The relation of homotopy equivalence is an equivalence relation. So if you can show that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{\pm1/2\}$, and that $Y$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{C} \setminus\{\pm 1/2\}$, it follows that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $Y$.

Comment: No  I know that homotopy equivalence is an equivalence relation. But what I did not get is  how $ \mathbb{C}$ is coming here?

Comment: I could as well have written $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{\pm(-1/2,0)\}$, but viewing $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $\mathbb{C}$ makes it easier to wright down a lot of things (probably also the homotopies, so you may interpret my using $\mathbb{C}$ as a suggestion.)

Comment: $Y$ is basically a realization in $\mathbb R^2$ of $S^1 \vee S^1$. The space $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $Y$ by collapsing the contractible subspace $\{0\} \times [-1,1]$.